# Create an SDL2 window via VNC

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, sdl, sdl-2, vnc

I have an application that creates a window using SDL2.
It works fine if an HDMI cable is connected.
Once I unplug the HDMI cable and access the machine via VNC, the window does not show up. No exceptions are thrown. Opening windows for other applications works as expected via VNC.

I removed the `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);` call. It works with and without it if an HDMI cable is connected. Otherwise, it fails with `No available displays`.

How can this issue be fixed or debugged?

Comment: I remember VNC having some problems with GL windows. Maybe force SDL to use a software renderer?

Comment: I currently don't use any renderer at all. Just an empty window. This part is the same in [this example](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer).